# When does $i^x=x$

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-writing, logarithms

Can someone please help me solve $i^x=x$?

So far I have:

$$i^x=x$$
$$\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(i)}=x$$
$$e^{i\pi}=-1$$
$$e^{i\pi/2}=i$$
$$\frac{\ln(x)}{\frac{i\pi}{2}}=x$$
$$\ln(x)=\frac{i x \pi}{2}$$
$$2\ln(x)=i x \pi$$
$$e^{2ln(x)}=e^{ix\pi}$$

But from here, I don't know where to go (Also if I have any mistakes so far please let me know as well). Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)?

Comment: Yeah, why? I did actually think that it fit in somewhere, but I couldn't find a place.

Comment: While there's no elementary solution, this can be solved (if it converges - I haven't checked) using the Lambert W function; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function (and specifically example 3 under the examples) for an explanation of how to do this.

Comment: Can you assume real $x$?

Comment: No, you can't assume anything whatsoever. Just brute solve

Comment: Generally, not wise to write $\log_i$ or anything like that. $\ln$ is a naturally multi-valued function.

Comment: Complex logarithms are usually multivalued, but you evaluated $\ln(i)$ as a particular value.

Comment: I don't know can you give i as base for log? Isn't base in $(0,1) U (1,\infty)$

Comment: For the $\log_i$, just skip that step, start by taking the natural log of both sides and the formula after the $\log_i$ line will appear.

Comment: Are there multiple soultions here? I used base i to anticipate 1 solution

Comment: There are likely multiple solutions, yes.

Comment: I'd avoid writing $i^x$ in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Lambert W-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) is a function $W(z)$ which solves $z=W(z)e^{W(z)}$. It is a multi-valued function.

In this case, you are trying to solve:

$$e^{x\pi i/2} = x$$

of:

$$\frac{-\pi i}{2}=\frac{-x\pi i}{2}e^{-x\pi i/2} $$

So

$$x\frac{-\pi i}{2} = W(-\pi i/2)$$ or

$$x =\frac{2i}{\pi} W\left(\frac{-\pi i}{2}\right)$$

I don't think you can do better than this, and even then, this in only using one particular value for $i^x$ - you could also use $i^x=e^{5x\pi i/2}$.

This sort of problem is not even easy to solve when $i$ is replaced by a real number in $(0,1)$. For example:

$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^x = x$$ clearly has a real solution in $(0,1)$, but no closed form without the $W$ function.

Comment: Wait a minute. $x$ is only one number. Could you please explain (0,1) to me?

Comment: Could you be specific about your question? Are you only asking about the final equation? There is only one real root to that equation, but there will be more complex roots. $(0,1)$ is just the "open interval" of values $y$ satisfying $0<y<1$. I'm saying that if $y$ is such a value, $y^{x}=x$ obviously has a real root, but we have not formula for it without Lambert. @AAron

Comment: Never mind, you answered it

Answer (score 2):

Thomas Andrews has already provided the general solution.  I thought that it might be instructive to see another approach when we assume that $x$ is real valued.

Now, we know that $i=e^{i\pi(2\ell+1/2)}$ for all integers $\ell$.  Then,

$$i^x=x\implies e^{i\pi(2\ell +1/2)x}=x \tag 1$$

Taking real and imaginary parts of $(1)$ yields

$$\cos (2\ell +1/2)\pi x=x \tag 2$$

and

$$\sin (2\ell +1/2)\pi x=0 \tag 3$$

From $(3)$ we see we must have $x=\frac{k}{2\ell +1/2}$, for any integer $k$, whereupon substituting back into $(2)$ reveals $$\cos k\pi =\frac{k}{2\ell +1/2}$$

which has no solutions.  Thus, there are no real solutions to $i^x=x$.